# Rails Activerecord: How to exclude records with multiple associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the below query with the associations as shown.

The query works when there is only one booking record per bike, but fails when bike has multiple bookings and one or more meet the conditions and others do not. Since the other don't meet the conditions, they cause the associated bike to be returned as a result.

How do I write the query so that a bike is not returned as a query result when at least one of the bookings meets the where.not condition?

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
end 

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bike
end 

startDate = Date.parse("2018-10-10")
endDate = Date.parse("2018-10-19")

@bikes = Bike.joins(:bookings).where.not("(date_start BETWEEN (?) AND (?)) OR (date_start BETWEEN (?) AND (?)) OR (((?) OR (?)) BETWEEN date_start AND date_end)", startDate, endDate, startDate, endDate, startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: You could always do the SQL without creating models using `bike_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.execute(sql)` and then do something like `Bike.joins(:bookings).where(id: bike_ids)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the query on `Bike` with a subquery on `Booking`:

```
Bike.where.not(
  id: Booking.select('DISTINCT bike_id').where(...)
)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify the condition a bit. I have not considered edge cases but you can do something like this:

```
Bike.where.not(
    id: Booking.where("start_time < ? and end_time > ?", endDate, startDate
).group(:bike_id))
```

So basically `bookings.start_time` should be less then potential `endDate` while `bookings.end_time` is bigger than potential `startDate`. Hence you will get all bookings that are in the range of the potential new booking time range and adding `not` will select the opposite

I've tested my sample on a simple dataset and it excludes the bikes that are occupied. Please let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thanks for the response! I took one of the above answers, but I needed to break out the last bit into two to indeed simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse things, beginning the query with the bookings you want and finding the set of all their unique bikes:

```
@bikes = Booking.where.not(...).group(:bike_id).includes(:bikes).map{|b| b.bike}
```